# How do I access the last element of an array?

Tags: julia

I want to access the last element of some array.

I am using `length`:

```
last_element = x[length(x)]
```

Is this correct? Is there a canonical way to access the last element of an ordered collection in Julia?

Answer (score 16):

`length` is fine if your array uses standard indexing. However, `x[length(x)]` will not necessarily return the last element if the array uses [custom indexing](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/offset-arrays/).

A more general and explicit method is to use [`last`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.last), which will return the last element of an array regardless of indexing scheme:

```
julia> x = rand(3)
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.7633644675721114
 0.396645489023141 
 0.4086436862248366

julia> last(x)
0.4086436862248366
```

If you need the index of the last element, use [`lastindex`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.lastindex):

```
julia> lastindex(x)
3
```

The following three methods are equivalent:

```
julia> last(x)
0.4086436862248366

julia> x[lastindex(x)]
0.4086436862248366

julia> x[end]
0.4086436862248366
```

`x[end]` is syntax sugar for `x[lastindex(x)]`.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that `A[end]` is just a syntactic sugar for `A[lastindex(A)]`, they're equivalent.

Comment: Good point. I've edited the answer to make that more clear. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The ´end´ syntax also allows you to access the second last element etc. I cannot add a comment so i make this Answer.

```
A[end]   # last element
A[end-1] # second last
A[end-9] # 10th last
```

(provided they exist)