# How to get last element of array in Julia

Tags: julia

I have a very simple problem:
I want to get the last element of an array, so I tried:

```
length = 100
array = zeros(length,1)

array[:length]
```

I get the following error: ArgumentError: invalid index: :length of type Symbol

Can anybody help me solve this?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59722749/how-do-i-access-the-last-element-of-an-array , which likely is a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing you're looking for is `array[end]`:

```
> array[end]
# 0.0
```

`end` gets the last index of the array. For more information, [read the documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.lastindex).

Answer (score 4):

Some approaches. Keep in mind your data structure only has one dimension and you only want one element, so you don't need a colon when using indexing with `[`.

```
last(array)
0.0

array[lastindex(array)]
0.0
```

Comment: Actually, the data structure is two-dimensional, with size 100x1. For a proper one-dimensional vector, one can use `zeros(100)`.

Comment: @DNF True, although this can be reduced to a Vector without loss of data. I even think Matrix{T}(x, 1, 1) is or was a special case of Vector{T} and internally treated as Array{T}? Not entirely sure though, a lot of aliasing going on :)

Comment: I don't think that can be the case. `Matrix` is a constructor, and must necessarily either return a `Matrix`, or fail.

Comment: @DNF That's in part semantics, see `typeof(zeros(5, 1))` which gives `Matrix{Float64} (alias for Array{Float64, 2})`

Comment: But it cannot be `Vector`, is my point.

Comment: @DNF Yes, that's undeniable true. Not gonna argue about that. Only thing that I mean is that a Matrix{T, x,1} is de facto a vector stored in a Matrix structure. So this special case can be reduced without loss of information to a vector. Of course, to create that explicitly you have to use Vector{T} or Array{T, 1}.

Comment: It is good (even important) to distinguish between those cases though, otherwise the code has to consider the possibility of different sizes than 1, and the compiler can miss optimization possibilities.

Comment: @DNF Maybe you think I want them to be the same, never said that. The user should know why they used Matrix or Vector. If someone used a one column Matrix they might have a reason for it. But they should consider using a Vector instead if all they need is one dimension.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Though you did say the matrix was 1D, which caused the confusion 

Answer (score 2):

A couple issues here: first of all, you should avoid using `length` because that's usually imported from `Base`, so best to avoid that word. Secondly, arrays are indexed using scalars, so even if you had a symbolic variable you'd want to use (say `:len`) you'd still write it as `array[len]` because you want the value, not the symbol itself. Finally, as the other answer states, `array[end]` should solve your problem without needing the symbolic variable.